# I wanted to solve a pixel problem on my figma I need

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, prototype, user-experience, figma

When I move something, whether it's a rectangle, text and other things are in decimal numbers, they don't move pixel by pixel, I wanted a way to fix this because yesterday it was still normal

I tried to move objects and others but they are in decimal numbers, I hope they move pixel by pixel with before and not in decimal numbers

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've turned off 'Snap to pixel grid'

To turn it on, go to Figma settings (The icon in the top left) -> Preferences -> Snap to pixel grid